# Error when trying to create my table in sqlalchemy => sqlalchemy.exc.OperationalError: (sqlite3.OperationalError) no such table: dht_new

Tags: python, sqlite, sqlalchemy, flask-sqlalchemy, create-table

It cant find my db even tho i have created it wite create_table? I have tried to put the function 
create_Table" in diffrent places with no result? However i get the error,

```
sqlalchemy.exc.OperationalError: (sqlite3.OperationalError) no such table: dht_new
[SQL: INSERT INTO dht_new (name) VALUES (?)]
[parameters: (None,)]
```

app.py

```
import os
from flask import Flask, request, jsonify
from flask_restful import Resource, Api
from flask_sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy
from db import db


app = Flask(__name__)

app.config['SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI'] = os.environ.get('SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI', 'sqlite:///newdata.db')
app.config['SQLALCHEMY_TRACK_MODIFICATIONS'] = False

db = SQLAlchemy(app)

@app.before_first_request
def create_tables():
    db.create_all()


class fixdb(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = 'dht_new'

    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key =True)
    name = db.Column(db.String(80))


    def __init__(self, temp):
        self.temp = temp

    def add_to_db(self):
        db.session.add(self)
        db.session.commit()


@app.route('/get', methods=['GET'])
def postrandom():
    temp = {'temperature': '23'}
    test_temp = fixdb(temp)

    test_temp.add_to_db()
    return jsonify(temp)



if __name__ == '__main__':
    from db import db
    db.init_app(app)
    app.run(port=5000, debug=True)
```

Answer (score 1):

run.py

```
from app import app
from db import db

db.init_app(app)

@app.before_first_request
def create_tables():
    db.create_all()
```

Comment: Welcome to SO - I'm coming from the Low Quality posts queue. I suspect your answer really does answer OP's issue, but could do with some more explanation! Specifically that the `if __name__ ..` path is likely not being taken.

Answer (score 0):

You need to create table first in your SQLite database. You can use the `SQLite Browser` to do the same else use the python CLI to create the table. Since you didn't mention your `.py` file name so I can't exactly show you the code but it would be something like this
first type `python` in your terminal, then

```py
from app import db
db.drop_all()
db.create_all()
```

and this should do it for you.

Comment: Thanks! I tried it but with no greater result unfortunately:/